# How to automatically update UILabels in RearViewRevealController when logging in/out?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, uilabel

I'm having trouble automatically updating UILabels when I log in and out of my app that I'm building. Like I can get them to update if I close and reopen the `RearViewRevealController (MenuVC)`. But is there a way to automatically update them without having to reopen the menu each time users log in/out?

// MenuVC

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser , !user.isAnonymous {
            // We are logged in
            logInOutBtn.setTitle("Logout", for: .normal)
            if UserService.userListener == nil {
                UserService.getCurrentUser {
                    self.fullNameTxt.text = UserService.user.fullName
                    self.emailTxt.text = UserService.user.email
                }
            }
        } else {
            logInOutBtn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
            fullNameTxt.text = "Sign in or create an account"
            emailTxt.text = "to continue"
        }
    }
```

// UserService

```
    func getCurrentUser(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {

            guard let authUser = auth.currentUser else { return }
            let userRef = db.collection("users").document(authUser.uid)

            userListener = userRef.addSnapshotListener({ (snap, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                guard let data = snap?.data() else { return }
                self.user = User.init(data: data)
                completion()
            })
}
```

Comment: Use Notifications?

Comment: Will Notifications update the view with the updated UILabels?

Comment: Auth.auth().currentUser is asynchronous process , can you try update labels on dispatch.main.async{} block.

Comment: How do I do the dispatch.main.async{} block?

Answer (score 0):

can update label by using UserDefault.

```
label.text = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultKey.name)
```

Then, forexample, can save username to UserDefault when log in

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: UserDefaultKey.name)
```

and when logout, set its value to "".